# TOMCAT 7, Can't change the heap size

Tags: java, tomcat, debian, tomcat7

I Have set the heap size of tomcat 7 by adding boot script:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx248m"
```

I change /etc/init.d/tomcat7 :

```
if [ -z "$JAVA_OPTS" ]; then
        JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx2048M -Xms1024M"
fi
```

I Reboot the computer and restart the Tomcat:

```
service tomcat7 restart
```

And verify the $CATALINA_OPTS Works:

```
> echo $CATALINA_OPTS
-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m
```

But when I go to the tomcat manager, I note that the heap has not changed.

```
Free memory: 38.02 MB Total memory: 123.75 MB Max memory: 123.75 MB
```

Please, i need help about this.

Comment: This question has been asked before..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `setenv.sh` in `tomcat/bin`, according to manual this should be the right place to put those params.

Another option, it depend on your OS tomcat package, may be that config param are overrided in `/etc/conf.d/tomcat/` or `/etc/tomcat`. Just check your init script and your catalina.sh to find where your settings are overrided.

Btw if you run a `ps -ef | grep tomcat` you should see the full command line with arguments: this may give you an idea of how init script build the command, and so you can investigate where params are set.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a setenv.sh script in the $CATALINA_HOME/bin directory with your options in it?

I find that setting JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx2048m -Xms1024m" in there works pretty well.

Comment: $CATALINA_HOME is not set, when i try to do "echo $CATALINA_HOME", returned none.

Comment: Ok - I'm not positive you need $CATALINA_HOME set, but you can definitely try putting the setenv.sh script in `<wherever tomcat is installed>/bin`

Comment: Works setting $CATALINA_OPTS in /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/setenv.sh  "export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xms1024m"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx2048m"
"